# Why are world maps cut off?

Tags: maps

I'm afraid that this isn't strictly a travel question, but I scoured the list of StackExchange sites and couldn't find any that seemed more appropriate.

When I look at a world map, I *always* need to remind myself that the equator is lower (farther south) than where I expect it to be. I always chalked this up to some kind of unconscious bias towards the Northern Hemisphere because I live there.

But today I was looking more closely at the latitude lines on a world map, and discovered that there were more northern latitude lines than southern latitude lines! The bottom part of the map must have been cut off, I guess. I clicked through the search results and discovered that this seemed to be ubiquitous. Here are some examples: [1](https://www.swiftmaps.com/wp-content/uploads/World-Classic-Elite.jpg), [2](https://onlinehomeopathictreatment.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/World-Maps-International-printable-World-Map-Photos.jpg), [3](http://www.wpmap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/RandWorldOPT.jpg), [4](https://lashworldtour.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/World-Map-with-Latitude-Longitude.jpg), [5](https://www.polartrec.com/files/members/jamie-esler/images/uniworld.jpg), [6](https://atlasoficeandfireblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/world-map-latitude.jpg). Some even cut off Antarctica entirely!

I did find a few counter examples, like [this one](https://assets.onxmaps.com/images/latitude-longitude-global-map.jpg?mtime=20180521120041). But they seem to be a tiny minority.

This is extremely disorienting to me. I strongly feel that the equator ought to go through the *middle* of the map, and that a world map should show the *whole* world. Why are most maps made this way?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This isn't really a question about travel, but about cartography. The simple answer is that no one lives in Antarctica and almost no one travels to Antarctica, while the great majority of the world's land, population, wealth, and map purchasers are located in the northern hemisphere. Every flat map, by definition, is a distortion that misrepresents the earth in one way or another, and the people who care about Antarctica will pay extra for specialized maps of it.

Comment: The obvious answer is "Because Antarctica is boring", but there is actually a SE site dedicated to exactly this topic - https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ ("Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals")

Comment: I will note additionally that all your examples are political maps, and there are no political borders, capitals, or the like to represent in Antarctica.

Comment: @choster There are 7 countries that make [territorial claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_claims_in_Antarctica#Other_European_claims) to various bits of Antarctica, so to say that there are no political borders on that continent isn't strictly true.

Comment: @Doc I read the ["What topics can I ask about here?" help page for the GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I didn't feel that my question belonged there. Was I incorrect? None of the topics listed seem relevant to this, to me. But it's possible I just don't understand them properly. I'm not exactly a cartographer.

Comment: I also don't feel like "Antarctica is boring", whether it is true or not, is a good reason to leave it off a map.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the purpose and development of maps, https://history.stackexchange.com may ve more appropriate

Comment: GIS stack rejected the migration, I fear that History stack would as well, lack of research in the question likely. Some questions do not really fit the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 2):

Each map will be designed to serve a specific purpose, which may lead to comprises in how it is rendered.

A map that concentrates on political details (borders), doesn't really (other than possibly the coastline) need areas that don't have political borders.

[image]

The Northern Hemisphere has a larger land mass, where more details are needed (paper space), so the area south of the Antarctica coastline (which has no details to show) is often simply left out.

[image]

A pure **shipping lane** may may even leave out northern areas, so that more space is available for details which the designer wants to concentrate on.

A map of the world (for navigation purposes i.e. flat) the **placement** within the planet (Mercator projection) will show those areas that are otherwise not needed. The **size** of each area is, however, distorted.

[image]

- Greenland is shown here as being larger than Africa

[image]

The Peters Projection attempts to correct the distortion of the Mercator projection, giving a more realistic size relation. In width, the maximum northern/southern are still distorted giving an incorrect impression of its shape. For navigation, however, thus type of map is usefull. Distances are more realisticly displayed.

---

A map that concentrates on the shape and size of the land masses, may look completely different.

[image]

- Greenland size is being shown here realisticly (i.e. smaller than Africa)

For navigation purposes this map would not be used.

So when selecting a map, it is important to know for what porpose the map was intended for.

---

**Sources**:

- [World Maps | Maps of all countries, cities and regions of The World](https://ontheworldmap.com/)
- [Map lets you visualize shipping traffic around the world | Canadian Geographic](https://www.canadiangeographic.ca/article/map-lets-you-visualize-shipping-traffic-around-world)
- [Finally, a World Map That Doesn't Lie | Discover Magazine](https://www.discovermagazine.com/environment/finally-a-world-map-that-doesnt-lie)
- [AuthaGraph　オーサグラフ　世界地図](https://www.authagraph.com/projects/description/%E3%80%90%E4%BD%9C%E5%93%81%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC%E3%80%91%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B01/?lang=en)
- [Gall–Peters projection - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall%E2%80%93Peters_projection)

Comment: The gall peters projection is not better for navigation than the mercator. Any rectangular projection distorts east-west distances. The mercator and peters projections also distort north-south distances, but they do so in an opposite way . The mercator distorts north-south distances such that at any given point the north-south scale matches the east-west scale and local shapes and distances make sense. The peter's does the opposite, it makes the east-west scale inversely proportional to the north/south scale so that area is preserved across the map but local shapes and angles are not.

Comment: there are also maps that put South or Eat on top instead of North

Answer (score 2):

Projecting from a (roughly) spherical object onto a flat plane, is a messy business. There are many projections, each with their pros and cons.

In particular any map that tries to keep north/south as up/down and west/east as left/right across the map is inevitably going to badly distort the polar regions. Some projections (such as the mercator projection) theoretically have infinite hight, so a cut must be made somewhere. For other projections cutting off the map is purely a practical and artistic choice.

On a political map, there is some sense in including the northern coastlines of the northern countries, even if they are badly distorted to show clearly which bit of land belongs to this country.

Antarctica on the other hand will always be horribly distorted on a rectangular map and doesn't really have any meaningful political borders. Some countries do have claims and mutually recognize each others claims, but other countries with a presence in Antarctica don't.